# Why the file contains only the print from first iteration

Tags: c, loops, file-io, printf

I wrote this code in C to print nos from 1 to 10 in a txt file one by one but after the execution only first no is printed in the txt file. pls help

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 int main()
 {
     int i;
     FILE *fptr;

     fptr=fopen("C:\\program.txt","w");

     for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
     {
         fprintf(fptr,"\n%d\n",i);
         fclose(fptr);
     }
 }
```

Comment: this is not c++, so please remove the 'c++' tag

Comment: fclose(fptr); take it out of for loop, add a return statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't close the file until you finish writing to the file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{

    int i;

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("C:\\program.txt","w");


    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {


        fprintf(fptr,"\n%d\n",i);
    }
    fclose(fptr);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `fclose()` after the `for` loop body.

Otherwise, you'll be closing the file pointer after the very first iteration and all the successive loops involving the pointer will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you'll be using an *invalid* file pointer (already closed).

Comment: @user2860094 no, please notice the _loop body_ part properly.

Answer (score 2):

After the first iteration of the loop you close the file descriptor with `fclose`. Move it out of the loop below it.

As `man fclose` says:

> [...] any further access (including another call to `fclose()`) to the stream results in undefined behavior.

---

Notes:

- you should check the return value of `fopen`